# Prepping File From Zbrush to Blender Rendering

Tags: zbrush

Trying to work out a workflow for taking my highly detailed ring designs in Zbrush into Blender for rendering.   I can bring into Keyshot from Zbrush and render just fine but when taking the same thing into Blender for rendering its totally bogged down and slower than molasses.  Can anyone give me an idea how to get these high detail sculpts to work in Blender rendering ?[image]

Comment: ZBrush can handle more geometry than other 3d software packages including Blender because it uses proprietary algorithms different than other 3d packages. What kind of polycounts are we talking about? You probably need to get the polycount down. That shouldn't be a problem, because the objects might be way too dense to keep the same form. Decimating them before export might be a solution. i hesitate to put it as an answer, because of the lack of context provided. It's a guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'm decimating down to 600k in Zbrush before exporting in FBX. When opening in Blender it was over 4 million faces.  Wondering how best to lower polycount without sacrificing detail ?  Hoping there is a reasonably automated way to prep from Zbrush to Blender

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/JoseConseco/GoB ?

Comment: I would try to avoid .fbx format whenever possible when using Blender. Can you get away with .obj maybe? Maybe fbx is imported as separate faces or something like that...